# AdellePE Bold font in css

Tags: css, fonts, adobe, typekit

I have a text whose font-family is AdellePE Bold I am wondering how can I use it in our CSS?

```
.blog-text
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 100px;
    color: rgb(254, 91, 31);
    font-family: AdellePE Bold ;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: .24em;
}
```

I am using the above code but unfortunately its not matching the font of the text.

Comment: Has the font been declared before this class ?

Comment: @No. How can I declare it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the font-face as below with

```
@font-face {
font-family: AdellePE Bold;
src: url(fonts/[FONT NAME].woff);
}
```

Replace [FONT NAME] above with your font name for the font file. Your font might need single quotes to work so be sure to check that.

```
.blog-text
{
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
font-weight: bold;
left: 100px;
color: rgb(254, 91, 31);
font-family: AdellePE Bold ;
font-size: 30px;
letter-spacing: .24em;
}
```

Let me know if it works.